# Pyside2 python resizing pixmap being displayed in GUI

Tags: python, pyside2

How would I resize an image that im displaying in my gui using pixmap and label

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path_to_image)
image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

then i display that label in my gui.

I did try this but it did not work

```
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(50, 50, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Comment: *where* did you try that? If you're rescaling the pixmap *after* calling `setPixmap` it will never work, as you're not updating the current one, you're creating a *new* one. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `image_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(50, 50, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))`.